# WSHttpBinding binding, client authentication

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding, wcf-authentication

i am new to wcf and using wshttpbinding ,but i want to remove the user name and password form the service client (which i have to pass), 
my client code is

```
RServiceClient serviceClient = new RServiceClient();
serviceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "UserName";
serviceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";
```

i dont want to pass this username and password.

my client app.config is:

```
     <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IRService" 
              closeTimeout="00:01:00"
              openTimeout="00:01:00" 
              receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
              sendTimeout="00:01:00"
              bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
              transactionFlow="false"    
              hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
              maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
              messageEncoding="Text" 
              textEncoding="utf-8" 
              useDefaultWebProxy="true"
              allowCookies="false">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                            maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                            maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                            maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <reliableSession ordered="true" 
                               inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                               enabled="false" />
              <security mode="Message">
               <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                          proxyCredentialType="None"
                          realm="" />
               <message clientCredentialType="Windows"                    
                        negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
```

rite now service is hosted in a web.
is there any change in service.config or client side app .config.
in my weak knowledge after googleing is that change should be the client side but i m unable to do that. :-(

note: my contract requires sessions too.
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the web.config at the server side, your client web.config will be automatically updated after a refresh on the web reference.
If you do not want to use login/password, i can advice you to set up a mutual certificate authentication.

This approach is secure and interoperable with other WS stacks (eq. Java CXF, ...)

For Mutual Certification Authentication :
You will need a X.509 certificate to allow the client to be sure that the server is really who is pretend to be and an other X.509 certificate at the client-side.

Here an example of web.config, more informations at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733102.aspx) :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceCredentialBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="Contoso.com" 
                                storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                storeName="My" 
                                x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceCredentialBehavior" 
               name="ServiceModel.Calculator">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/Calculator" 
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="InteropCertificateBinding"
                  name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator"
                  contract="ServiceModel.ICalculator" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="InteropCertificateBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"
                     negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                     establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thats what i am asking, what is the change in service.config? this is my config.<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="RServiceBehavior" name="EHRService"><endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ServiceContracts.IRService"><identity><dns value="localhost" /></identity></endpoint>